# STOMP messages sent to durable address/queue not surviving reboots

Tags: stomp, activemq-artemis

I'm getting started with ActiveMQ Artemis and would like to send STOMP messages to a queue:

```xml
<address name="/queue/default">
    <multicast>
        <queue name="/queue/default">
            <durable>true</durable>
        </queue>
    </multicast>
</address>
```

As best to my knowledge as I can tell, I've made a best effort to make it so that messages in this queue will survive a restart, yet for some reason, when I restart my broker, all the messages are gone.

What would I be missing in this situation that could cause this to happen?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to send the STOMP message?

Comment: Not really, I'm using an abstraction library for laravel. What I call is just a framework interface... Although I'm happy to hear your angle of thinking here? How could it be significant?

Comment: How you send the message will determine which headers get set on the message which will determine how the broker will deal with the message so it's pretty important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details about how you're sending the message it's hard to answer with confidence, but I'm guessing that you're not setting the proper header on the message to indicate that it should be durable/persistent. The STOMP specification doesn't outline the behavior of messages in this regard so it's up to the messaging provider (i.e. ActiveMQ Artemis in this case) to determine the behavior. By default messages will not be durable/persistent so you must set the `persistent` header on the message to `true` to make the message durable/persistent.

It's also worth noting that queues are durable by default so you don't really need `<durable>true</durable>` in the definition as it's redundant.